# Is it true that if $b_1, b_2, b_3 \in V$ then $\operatorname{Span}(B) \subseteq V$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it true that if $B = \{b_1, b_2, b_3\} \subseteq V$ and $V$ is a subspace, then $\operatorname{Span}(B)\subseteq V$ ?

$B=\{b_1, b_2, b_3\}$ in this example is a set of column vectors but my question is if it's true for any kind of vectors.

If so, can you give me a quick intuition on why?

Comment: What is meant by $Sp(B)$ here? Is it the linear span?

Comment: $Sp(B) = \{{a_{1} \cdot B_{1} + a_{2} \cdot B_{2} + ... + a_{n} \cdot B_{n} \mid a_{1} , ... , a_{n} \in \mathbb{R}}\}$

Answer (score 1):

It's true,recall that if $\mathbb{V}$ is a subspace over $\mathbb{R}$ then,for all u,v $\in\mathbb{V}$ and $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$:

$u+v\in\mathbb{V}$ and 
$\alpha v\in\mathbb{V}$ 
then $Sp(u,v)\subseteq\mathbb{V}$ follow from these properties because $Sp(u,v)=\alpha_1u +\alpha_2v$ with $\alpha_1,\alpha_2\in\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's true. There are certain properties all vector spaces (and subspaces) have. One is that they are closed under linear combinations. Since the span of a set of vectors is exactly all the linear combinations of those vectors, all of the vectors in the span are also vectors of the subspace, and so the span is a subset of the subspace.

Another way to say this is that the span is a subspace of the subspace $V$.

Comment: But how can I know that $B4$ for example is also in $V$? Maybe $\{B1, ... , B4\}$ is linearly independent?

Comment: What is this $B4$?